# No Plots Show Up In Plots Window

Tags: r, rstudio, networkd3

When I execute my code from the Source Window, everything appears to work, except the Plots window comes up empty. BUT if I copy just the line of code that generates the plot and paste it into the Console, the intended plot shows up fine. This is happening with the networkD3 package, but the basic R function *plot* works fine.

Here's an example:

```
library(networkD3)

setwd("/Users/steve-guest/Desktop")

nodes <- read.csv("nodes.csv",header = TRUE)
edges <- read.csv("edges.csv",header = TRUE)

forceNetwork(Links = edges, 
             Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target", 
             NodeID = "Name",
             Group = "Group", 
             opacity = 0.6, 
             legend = TRUE,
             zoom = TRUE)
```

data is [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ddbf78770341e70415f36cc0c5e2419d20170507163220/d5bc91)

If I execute this code, I get no errors and no plot. If I copy the "forceNetwork" command into the Console, I get this:[image: screenshot]

Also, no export/Save As functions seem to work for plots.

Seems I need to add something. Anyone know what? I have RStudio v. 1.0.143 and R version 3.4.0 on a MacBook Pro running Sierra. All of my packages are up-to-date.

Comment: by the way, the image of the network plot was a screenshot.

Comment: if you make a reproducible example I can help you

Comment: Thanks CJ. The example is in my question - the code snippet.

Comment: I can not reproduce it if you don't give the data you are working with

Comment: ahh ... good point!!

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ddbf78770341e70415f36cc0c5e2419d20170507163220/d5bc91

Comment: what is the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143618/discussion-between-steve-and-cj-yetman).